# What does "group by desc" do in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I noticed by accident that this doesn't seem to be a syntax error like I would have expected

```
select `InvoiceNumber`, `_Total`, date(`__Added`)`Date` 
from `orders`
where`__Added`>=curdate()-interval 7 day
group by `Date`desc
order by `Date`;
```

Removing it doesn't appear to change my results, and `desc` doesn't appear anywhere on the doc page for `group by` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Is it just thrown out by the parser? Or does using `group by desc` actually do something?

Comment: `desc` and `asc` are for ordering the results.  Not sure if they have any relationship with `group by`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

from the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)

> Prior to MySQL 8.0.13, MySQL supported a nonstandard syntax extension that permitted explicit ASC or DESC designators for GROUP BY columns.

It probably stems from MySQL `GROUP BY` also implied ordering as well; at least did at one time, they stated a while back the feature was deprecated, but I am not sure if has actually been removed yet.

Comment: Ah that's why it wasn't doing anything in my case; because I also had an `order by`, that makes sense

Comment: And yes, on my 8.0 instance it is actually a syntax error

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the order by, you'll see that the result set is ordered by the group asc/desc direction.

Of course this is bad practice, don't expect it to be portable across DBMS.